# Saving an email change within the default Membership Provider in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am trying to set and save an email change using within the Membership Provider in ASP.NET MVC 3.  I do not know how to properly set and change the email property within the Membership Provider.

MSDN seems to suggest the MembershipUser.Email Property as it, "Gets or sets the e-mail address for the membership user," but I do not know how to get this to function properly.

I am attempting to use this code:

```
// change email
MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
u.Email = email; // Is this working as expected?
u.Save();  // this line doesn't do anything - what should it be?
db.Save();  <-- that is what I would do with ordinary database changes, but I don't know what context to use for Membership Provider changes. . .
```

EDIT:

I figured it out:

```
// change email
MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
u.Email = email;
System.Web.Security.Membership.UpdateUser(u);
```

Comment: I figured it out:     // change email
    MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
    u.Email = email;
    System.Web.Security.Membership.UpdateUser(u);  -- I have too little reputation to answer my own question within 8 hours though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try UpdateUser:

```
var user = Membership.GetUser(id);
user.Email = "new@email.com";
Membership.UpdateUser(user);
```

Comment: Thank you. System.Web.Security.Membership.UpdateUser(u);

Comment: I too am having the same problem as @Lakshay. This does NOT update my user's membership information.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to emphasise a point, following on from @Ecnalyr and @jwaern. When changing the email address, assigning the email address directly as follows did  not work:

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser.email = newEmail '(this won't work)
```

First, as shown in the responses above, one must assign the MembershipUser to a variable, and only then affect an UpdateUser on that variable.

```
Dim mu As MembershipUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser
mu.Email = email
Membership.UpdateUser(mu)
```