# How to update an MVC User Membership record?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

I have read a few different articles but I don't think they apply to my scenario.

I am trying to update a profile attached to a user; however, it won't let me get past the ModelState.IsValid part because I don't include the password fields.

I want to update some fields, but not the password fields.  So, how do I omit these from the RegisterModel?

Here is my code:

```
'
' POST: /Account/EditRegistry

<HttpPost()> _
Public Function EditRegistry(registerModel As RegisterModel) As ActionResult

    If ModelState.IsValid Then

        ' get membership from user name
        Dim user = Membership.GetUser(registerModel.UserName)

        ' get user profile
        Dim db0 = New UserProfileDbContext
        Dim profile = db0.UserProfiles.Where(Function(p) p.UserId = user.ProviderUserKey).Single()

        ' TODO: update profile
        profile.IsCompanyOwner = registerModel.IsCompanyOwner
        profile.IsBlogOwner = registerModel.IsBlogOwner
        profile.CompanyId = registerModel.Company
        profile.BlogId = registerModel.Blog
        db0.Entry(profile).State = EntityState.Modified
        db0.SaveChanges()

        ' get model changes to membership object


        ' update membership object from model


    End If

    ' If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    Return View(registerModel)

End Function
```

Edit:

Idea!  Do I have to create a new model for this?

Comment: For anyone looking to update aspects of the membership model itself, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245017/saving-an-email-change-within-the-default-membership-provider-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new view model that doesn't contain the `Password` field and then have your `EditRegistry` controller action take this view model as parameter instead of the `RegisterModel` domain model.

Comment: That is what I've done; however, it's still not validating the model and it's not showing me any validation messages.  It just says, "Account modification was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again."  But, my @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.Email) aren't showing any errors.

Comment: Try putting a `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)` in your view to display a list of all validation errors.

Comment: Yes, Darin!  You did it, again!  The problem was my username field, but I couldn't see that until I added the validation summary.